# get values and name from select option

Tags: php

how to insert 2 values (rate,name) into table from UI as a seperate column

for eg. :

```
$sql="SELECT code,rate, name FROM price_detail WHERE ref_no='VACC'"; 
  echo "<select   onchange='vaccines(this)' name='student' value='0'>
<option> Select Vaccines Type</option>";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row){
        echo "<option value=$row[rate]>$row[name]</option>"; 
                        }
    echo "</select>";
```

any suggestion i need to insert 2 filed like rate and name

Comment: You can use comma in option value; like below.

echo "<option value=\"$row[rate],$row[name]\">$row[name]</option>";

Comment: Please explain the question. What is your real requirement?

Comment: i need one select option like this
echo "<option value=$row[rate]>$row[name]</option>";

if user select any one othe optio like this 
"<option value='20'>bus</option>";
"<option value='60'>train</option>";

i need to insert to colum like rate=20 name= bus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, for example:

```
echo "<select   onchange='vaccines(this)' name='student' value='0'>
<option> Select Vaccines Type</option>";
    foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row)
        echo "<option value=\"$row[rate]|$row[name]\">$row[name]</option>"; 

    echo "</select>";
```

And then, in PHP script:

```
list($rate, $name) = explode('|', $_POST['student']);
```

You can change the separator to whatever characters sequence you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need both `$row['rate']` and `$row['name']` after POSTing the form. So, you need to specify both of them as the `value` attribute of the `<option>`.

Try this:

```
$sql="SELECT code, rate, name FROM price_detail WHERE ref_no='VACC'"; 
echo "<select onchange='vaccines(this)' name='student'>
<option value='0'>Select Vaccines Type</option>";
foreach ($dbh->query($sql) as $row){
 echo "<option value='$row[rate],$row[name]'>$row[name]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```

Then use [`list()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php) and [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get them in separate variables.

Try:

`list($rate,$name) = explode(',',$_POST['student']);`

Now you will have the rate of selected option in `$rate` and name of the selected option in `$name`.